# Is it possible to use Send-MailMessage with default credentials?

Tags: powershell, email

I've been trying to write a powershell script that sends an automated email as part of it's process using the logged in user's credentials. There are two primary methods that I've found to do this: `Send-MailMessage` and using a `Net.Mail.SmtpClient` object.

I've been able to get it up and running using the `Net.Mail.SmtpClient` object without issue, however that API is marked obsolete and so I'd prefer to not use it if possible, however I haven't been able to get `Send-MailMessage` to work using default credentials.

Without `UseDefaultCredentials` both of the scripts below fail with the same general message.

```
$smtpServer = "server.com"
$smtpFrom = "user@server.com"
$smtpTo = "user@server.com"
$messageSubject = "THIS IS WHERE YOUR SUBJECT GOES"
$messageBody = "This is a test of automated email at $([datetime]::Now.ToString('dd.MM.yyyy - HH.MM.SS'))"
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.EnableSsl = $true
$smtp.Port = 587
#$smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$smtp.Send($smtpFrom,$smtpTo,$messagesubject,$messagebody)
```

and

```
$mailsplat = @{
    SmtpServer = 'server.com'
    From = 'user@server.com'
    To = 'user@server.com'
    Subject = 'THIS IS WHERE YOUR SUBJECT GOES'
    Body = "This is a test of automated email at $([datetime]::Now.ToString('dd.MM.yyyy - HH.MM.SS'))"
    Port = 587
    UseSSL = $true
    #UseDefaultCredentials = $true
}
Send-MailMessage @mailsplat
```

> "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server 
>   response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated"

Fixing the first script is easy. If I uncomment out the `UseDefaultCredentials` line it works perfectly as expected. There's no `UseDefaultCredentials` or similar parameter available to `Send-MailMessage` however. I'd prefer to use the `Send-MailMessage` as it's the recommended method and the other is marked as obsolete, but I can't actually find a way to make it work with my requirements (despite a plethora of posts saying `Send-MailMessage` will use default credentials if none are provided and the documentation indicating it should)